# Google Analytics Data API: Why is the metric total different than when I split it by date?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

When I use the [query eplorer](https://ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/query-explorer/) I get unexpected results.

advertiserAdCost by Campaign: 520
advertiserAdCost by Campaign and Date: 305

The sole difference in the requests is the adding of the date dimension.

What could cause the difference?
[image: metric total after adding date dimension]
[image: metric total without adding date dimension]

Already checked which dates are available from api and it only goes to sept 22 whereas request is up to 2nd october. I'm not sure what this means.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo Okay. Help me understand please. You say it's about understanding analytics and multi dimensional databases. How is it about understanding a multi dimensional database? In what way am I missing this when I say splitting a total metric on a date dimension should not result in a different total?